# Templates bad cast object

Tags: c++11, templates, types, casting

I have the following problem. There is a function:

```
int main()
{
   //...
   std::string test = "1234";
   std::string result = ValueToCharArray(test);
   //...
}
template<class Type>
std::string ValueToCharArray(Type& value)
{
    std::string buffer = "";
    //...
    if (typeid(std::string) == typeid(value))
    {
        std::cout << typeid(std::string).name() << '\n' << typeid(value).name() << '\n';
        value.at(0);
        //...
    }
    short int i = 0;
    while (i<3)
    {
        buffer += '?';
        i++;
    }
    buffer[i] = 0;
    return buffer;
}
```

if i transfer string compiller give me next problem:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roLnU.png)

*error C2039: at: not member "std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits>" typetostring.h* (sorry for the language )

if i delete link from value variable "ValueToCharArray(Type value)" i get next error:

*error C2280: "std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits> &)": you can't get link in removed function*

I need to process it when a string type hits the function. VS say me this type it's std::ostream but this function link...

CAUTION!can using c++11 or c++14.The function is overloaded. It is not advisable to change the fx call. You cannot create a separate function for the string type. I will be grateful to everyone who will help at least a little. Sorry for the language :D

Comment: `std::sting::at` is new with C++20. It doesn't exist in C++11 . You could write `value[0]` instead.

Comment: The second error complains about an attempt to copy a stream object (perhaps by passing it to a function by value), somewhere in the code not shown.